# create distinct objects in a loop in js

Tags: node.js

var subject = [] ;
var subjectTemplate = {GUID:"", Title:"", Description:""};

for (var x = 0; x < 5; x++) {

```
var  clsSubject =   subjectTemplate;

    clsSubject.GUID = id.generateRandomNumber()
    clsSubject.Title = "Intorduction to js";
    clsSubject.Description = "Subject to learn js"; 
    subject.push = clsSubject;
```

}

what is happening is that there are 5 references of the same object in the array. So after the last run; all the 5 objects in the array have the same values. The five objects in the array are identical. 
I need to create 5 distinct objects with distinct values in an array.

Answer (score 0):

After doing some research and have come with the following:

```
var subjects = [];
var subjectTemplate = {GUID:""};

for (var x = 0; x < 5; x++)
{
  var subject = Object.Create(subjectTemplate);
      subject.GUID = <generate GUID>;
      subjects[x] = subject;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

With javascript you do not need to declare or initialize the fields when you first initialize the object.

Replace

```
var  clsSubject =   subjectTemplate;
```

with

```
var clsSubject = {};
```

With your current implementation you set all clsSubject to the same object instance, namely subjectTemplate.

Answer (score -1):

You can just change the delcaration of `clsSubject` to create a new object. You can actually just fill in the properties directly if you want. Also you didn't push to the array correctly.

```
var clsSubject = { 
    GUID: id.generateRandomNumber(),
    Title: "Intorduction to js",
    Description: "Subject to learn js"
};
subject.push(clsSubject);
```